# What is the use of needs_threshold as a parameter for make_scorer function?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, metrics

The description of needs_threshold in make_scorer function is not well explained in my opinion. It only says "whether score_func takes a continuous decision certainty". What does that mean exactly? Also, is there a relation between needs_proba and needs_threshold parameters? Thanks!